# H2 database: h2 console not working with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I followed the next [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database) for h2 implementation. H2 works well, but the console isn't - the page isn't opened.

I tried many gifts, so my final application.properties looks so:

```
#Database settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name = false 
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console/
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

#swagger
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER

#Disable thymeleaf cashing
spring.template.cache = false;
```

dependencies:

```
ext {
    spring_boot_version = '2.6.6'
}

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:${spring_boot_version}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${spring_boot_version}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:${spring_boot_version}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:${spring_boot_version}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${spring_boot_version}"
    runtimeOnly "com.h2database:h2:1.4.193"

....
```

The uri I try to open:

`http://localhost:8080/h2-console`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
server.port=8080

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately still not working

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add the following configuration to the security config?

```
 http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
```

Ideally, you need to config (depending on the spring boot version) to allow access to /h2-console URL.
You can also publicise your security configuration so that I can have a look.